# VBA Excel internet button click when only href

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

could you please tell me how can I click on button when only I got is:

```
<div id="finder_tab.advanced" class="tabCont">
<div style="float:left;">
<a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:showFrame('finder_tab.advanced')">
</div>
<div class="tabDim tabLabelCont">
<div>
<a href="javascript:showFrame('finder_tab.advanced')">Advanced</a>
</div>
```

end

```
objIE.document.getElementById("finder_tab.advanced").Click
```

is no working

thanks!

Comment: You should click to anchor, not div. Try `objIE.document.getElementByClassName("tabDim tabLabelCont")` and click to its child. [Check this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746918/using-vba-to-click-on-a-link-button-in-an-ie-web-page)

Comment: It looks as though you are attempting to click on a div element.  You will probably need to find the javascript function "showFrame" and determine how to trigger it.  But I'm just guessing because it's not real clear what you are trying to do, other than click on a button.  And I don't see a button in the html code you provided.

Comment: thanks for answers! this is some kind of table with bookmarks or something: https://image.prntscr.com/image/f83ff346f7f64d5eb2d4ff86258a31ab.png
@JohnMuggins

Comment: Sorry, I'm blocked from that website.

Comment: @JohnMuggins http://i.imgur.com/ofMztaK.png now?

Comment: I apologize.  I'd like to help but my system will not allow me to download images.